# Deploying ear to Weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic, ear, weblogic12c

iI have an ear file which successfully deployed on JBoss7 & WebSphere 8.5
When trying on WebLogic 12c I'm getting this error at the AdminServer.log:

```
####<Apr 10, 2013 5:29:36 PM IDT> <Error> <J2EE> <wbl12t2.autowblciddmeronserver.autop> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1365604176997> <BEA-160228> <AppMerge failed to merge your application. Merge again with the -verbose option for more details. See the error message(s) below.>
####<Apr 10, 2013 5:30:09 PM IDT> <Debug> <Socket> <wbl12t2.autowblciddmeronserver.autop> <AdminServer> <ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1365604209078> <BEA-000450> <Socket 420 internal data record unavailable (probable closure due idle timeout), event received -32>
```

and this in the web console:

```
Error Unable to access the selected application.
Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Error com.demo.tasks.api.RTExecutor
Error com.demo.tasks.api.RTExecutor
```

The ear use jax-ws and jax-rs (using Jersey dependency).
the class com.demo.tasks.api.RTExecutor is interface with @WebService annotation.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Is there anyway to get more details about the problems (more log files I miss, etc..)?

Comment: hard to know without seeing the ear

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2165558 might help you

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving the same error code and, after a bit of digging, I found out that Weblogic wants the extension of you EAR to be all lower case, otherwise it considered it invalid.

So your application must be called **YourApp.ear** and cannot be called **YourApp.EAR** for example.